# не считает сумму

Tags: c++

```
void f1(int **arr, int n, int m, int sum, int k ){
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        sum = 0;
        k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            sum += arr[i][j];
        }
        if (sum > 0)
        {
            k++;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Так ведь смотря что вы передаете и как пытаетесь получить :) Может, вы вообще после вызова функции переданную ей в качестве аргумента переменную `sum` выводите, мало ли! Намёк: вызовите функцию как `f1(arr,0,0,0,0)`. Ничего не удивляет?

Comment: переменная `sum` - локальна, после завершения функции значение исчезает.

Comment: то есть данная функция должна быть int?

Comment: да, удобнее так и не забывать `return sum;`

Comment: но оно не работает, даже если return sum, k вернуть

Comment: я про запятую ничего не говорил

Comment: может сумму можно найти функцией?

Comment: return sum не помогает. Такое ощущение, что "sum += arr[i][j];" не выполняется

Comment: f1(A, q, w, sum1, k1 );

Comment: вы считаете сумму всех столбцов, непонятно, что вы хотите вернуть, все суммы? или последнюю? и зачем вы хотите вернуть переменную `k` - непонятно. вопрос был что не считает сумму чего-то.

Comment: это функция в основной программе

Comment: k - счетчик столбцов с положительной суммой элементов

Comment: Еще один намек, раз первый не помог... `int&sum, int&k`

Comment: у вас вопрос неправильный. программа все суммы считает. добавьте в вопрос, что именно вы хотите. суммы чего? количество чего? куда весь результат вкладывать?

Comment: для каждого массива проверить все ли столбцы имеют положительную сумму элементов

Comment: значит просто возвращаёте правду/ложь `bool f1(..`. переносите `k = 0;` в начало функции и возвращайте `return k==m;` или проще `if (sum < 0) return false;` и в конце `return true;`

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: а почему мы возвращаем k==m, и если не трудно как работает функция bool?

Answer (score -4):

У вас сумма и k не используются за пределами цикла, поэтому результаты суммирования и инкрементирования не сохраняются и не возвращаются из функции. Чтобы исправить это, лучше объявить сумму и k как переменные функции, а не как локальные переменные цикла:

```
int* f1(int **arr, int n, int m ){
    int sum = 0;
    int k = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            sum += arr[i][j];
        }
        if (sum > 0)
        {
            k++;
        }
    }
    int res[2] = {sum,k};
    return res;
}
```

Но в этом случае необходимо будет объявить res как глобальную переменную или выделить ей память на стеке.

Comment: вы возвращаете указатель на **мёртвый** массив `res`. ваш совет не *очень* .. 

Comment: один из самых успешных способов огрести неприятности, возврат адреса локальной переменной